# AWK/sed - write a text in a text file before number which is lower than specific value

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I have a text file. In this text file, I have numbers from lowest to highest.
Input example

```
[  Index 1  ]
1628 5704
32801 61605
71508 90612
102606
```

I want divide this file into two group of sections In the first I will have numbers between 1 and 58050 in the second I would have numbers between 58051 116100, so when my script find a number which is bigger than 58050 this program will write [  Index 2  ]

Expected output

```
[  Index 1  ]
1628 5704
32801 
[  Index 2  ]
61605
71508 90612
102606
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^\[/{ next }
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i>=1 && $i<=58050){
      tempfirstGroup=(tempfirstGroup?tempfirstGroup OFS:"")$i
    }
    if($i>=58051 && $i<=116100){
      tempsecondGroup=(tempsecondGroup?tempsecondGroup OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  if(tempfirstGroup){
      firstGroup=(firstGroup?firstGroup ORS:"")tempfirstGroup
  }
  if(tempsecondGroup){
      secondGroup=(secondGroup?secondGroup ORS:"") tempsecondGroup
  }
  tempsecondGroup=tempfirstGroup=""
}
END{
  print "[  Index 1  ]" ORS firstGroup ORS "[  Index 2  ]" ORS secondGroup
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[  Index 1  ]
1628 5704
32801
[  Index 2  ]
61605
71508 90612
102606
```

Comment: It works perfect, thank you so much. You have great programming skills.